# Transfer iPhone contacts to iCloud or Mac

Tags: iphone, mac, icloud, contacts

I just got involved into a new project at work, and I added all my colleagues to my iPhone contacts. In the middle of the process I got the idea it would be better to add the contacts to my iCloud.

So I got half of my colleagues in my iCloud and half of them on my iPhone memory. For some reason, the contacts I added on my iPhone, don't appear in my Address book. The ones I added on my iCloud do appear on my Mac and iPad (just like I want it to happen).

I've tried with iTunes and some 3th party software, but none of them worked (unless I paid for it... but I don't want to since I'm convinced this most basis function should work out of the box...)

So any advice how to transfer my iPhone contacts in vcf's to my Mac so I can import them into my Address book? Or how to transfer my iPhone contacts to my iCloud?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try [My Contacts Pro](http://itunes.apple.com/us/app/my-contacts-backup/id446784593) (Free). You could export all contacts on your iPhone and send them via e-mail, also could import them to your Address Book on your Mac.

Answer (score 1):

There is a free of charge BETA tool called copytrans contacts which will help you [transfer iPhone contacts](http://www.copytrans.net/iphone-contacts.php) to your computer. After that, import the contacts from your computer to your iCloud by logging in to iCloud on your computer and pointing to "Import".

Answer (score 0):

Go to you settings, select iCloud, then turn on contacts. then it should automatically update the contacts. For mail, turn on the "mail" option.

Answer (score 0):

To Sync an iPhone With New Mac just:

1. Quit iTunes on both Macs
2. Disconnect your iPhone from both Macs
3. Open the *Home* folder
4. Copy iTunes directory from the old computer to the new one located at: `~/Music/iTunes`
5. Open user library directory and copy the backups from the old computer to the new one located at: `~/Library/Application Support/MobileSync/`
6. Also copy over iTunes Preferences files located at: `~/Library/Preferences/com.apple.iTunes.plist`
7. Launch iTunes in the new Mac up
8. Authorize your Mac to Apple Server
9. Connect your iPhone and sync as usual

Answer (score -1):

Simply use <kbd>Command ⌘</kbd> + <kbd>A</kbd> to select all your "On my Mac" contacts, then drag and drop them onto your iCloud Contacts.

Comment: He wants to add iPhone contacts to his Mac. Not the other way around.

Comment: Darn! (^_^) Sorry.

Answer (score -1):

go onto icloud.com then open contacts
select the ones you want by clicking or ctrl and click for multiple then click the clog in the bottom left and chose export this should open contacts on your mac and ask to import the selected amount then its all done.

Comment: Can you elaborate a bit more on how this solves the problem stated in the question (where contacts entered on the phone do not seem to get synced)?